# best/simple way to run .bat file on remote machine

Tags: python

I have another machine on the same network, from my machine I can reach this remote machine (both are `Windows`).

On the remote machine I have `.bet` file that start some service.

What is the simplest way to reach this `.bat` file and run this file on the remote machine?

Comment: `Invoke-Command` in powershell or `wmic` with `/node` parameter in cmd.

Comment: Any tutorial  for this ?

Comment: Map the other computer as a network drive and run the bat like it is on your computer. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @balderman: i want to run the .bat file on the remote machine (where the file exist) not on my machine

Comment: @falukky . I completely understand :-). Once you  map the remote machine as local drive (lets assume drive R)   you will be able to run the bat `os.system("R:\\file.bat")`

Comment: this is it ? and this os.system('...') command will execute on the remote machine ?

Comment: Availability of remote execution measures are part of how malware spreads so quickly through Windows networks -- there's a reason they're being removed/mitigated/limited.