# run .bat file on remote machine

Tags: python

I try to run `.bat` file on remote machine.

From my machine i mapped the folder where my `.bat` (on the remote machine) is exist and from my machine i just try to run the file:

```
os.system(r'‪Y:\file.bat')
```

But it seems that nothing hapenning.

Any suggestions ?

BTW both machines are `Windows`

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/55326462/929999

Comment: yes i saw it and choose this approach but i have different issue that this not working

Comment: Are you attempting to run the _commands_ in the bat file on the remote machine? Because that won't work this way. What you are actually doing is running the commands in the `bat` file on the remote computer on the local computer you're executing this Python script on.

Comment: I try to run the os.system.. command on my machine, the bat file is on remote machine and this bat file need to run also on the remote machine, so what i need to do ?

Comment: You need to log into the other machine (remotely, if you wish) and then run the script there.

Comment: What do you mean log into the other machine ? i want to run this bar file automatically